# Results of Inmagic Presto DMS searches via the web service API are not in order of relevance

Tags: document-management

I am using the Presto Web Service API against a Presto 3.5 installation. When I call AdvanceSearchResultIds, passing a search phrase, the results are not ordered by the relevance of the result to the search phrase so the best results are not at the top. The results do not include a relevance score so I cannot order the results myself.

How do I get the results ordered by their relevance to the search phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inmagic supplied me with a fixed version of Inmagic.Mercury.Services.WCFServiceLib.dll to address this issue in Presto 3.5 SP1.